# Posting the date into my database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date

I am learning php at the moment and have decided on creating a simple to do list that works just as I wanted it to do. But I decided a good idea would be to add in a dat stamp of when the item was added to the to do list, you know, to keep it organised.

Now when I manually insert an item via phpmyadmin and select todays date, the page displays the date as expected. Yet when I submit an item via my script on the front end the date is set to 0000-00-00 and I am at a point where I am a little stuck, I believe it is to do with the part below not inserting anything relating to the date, but I am not sure what do, I have tried to research but am a little confused:

```
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content']);

$sql="INSERT INTO items (content) VALUES ('$content')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
header('Location: index.php');

mysqli_close($con);
```

The item is submitted via this form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="content">
<input type="submit" value="Add Item">
</form>
```

And displayed with this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM items");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['added'] . "<br>" . $row['content'];

  echo "<br>";

  echo "Mark as complete";

  echo "<br>";

  echo "<a onclick='confirmUser()' href='delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Delete Item</a>";

  echo "<br>";

  echo "<a href='update.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit Item</a>";    

  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";     

}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: I see nothing that is enforcing valid dates being inserted into your database. I bet your date format is incorrect.

Comment: Define a default value for the date column in your database

Comment: Doesn't "mysqli_real_escape_string" rather defeat the point of the whole mysqli API?

Comment: @MarkBaker So that did the trick, how do I handle the fact it is showing the time because I have to select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with DATETIME as will not allow me to just use DATE?

Comment: Format the value when you need to display it

Comment: @MarkBaker is this done in: $sql="INSERT INTO items (content) VALUES ('$content')";

Comment: This is kinda Databases 101, and it would take far longer than an answer here to explain the difference between reading from and writing to a database.... where do you actually need to show this date? is it part of the data you show after SELECT?

Comment: @MarkBaker Im new to all of this as explained above. Any pointers to where I can find such information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define default value for date column to current_timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

either set an default value in database, or add NOW() in your query.

```
example: 
$sql="INSERT INTO items (content, date) VALUES ('$content', NOW())";
```